# C: Initialize array of character pointers (strings) and iterate through a file using fgets to put value in these strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I want to create an array of character pointers (strings) of length 6
But I want to initialize them by iterating through a file which has `\n` separated exactly 6 lines

```
char* a[6];
FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    fgets(a[i], MAXLEN, fp);
}
```

But it gives me a segmentation error. 
If someone can first write the code for this and then explain what is exactly wrong, it will be great, thanks.

Comment: You have created an array containing six pointers, but the pointer values are never initialized or assigned.  `fgets()` does not do that.  Rather it tries to write data *where the provided pointer **points*** (which is indeterminate in your case).  You need to allocate space for each line of the file, not neglecting one byte for a string terminator for each.  This can be a bit tricky if you don't have an upper bound on the length you need, but you seem to be assuming a known maximum length.

Comment: Either (1) declare `a` as `char a[6][MAXLEN];`, or (2) dynamically allocate at least `MAXLEN` bytes for each `a[i]` to point to (and don't forget to free that space when you no longer need it), or (3) set each `a[i]` to the address of the first element of a large-enough existing array declared separately (`a[i] = &an_array[0];`, or, equivalently, `a[i] = an_array;`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here

```
char* a[6];
```

`a` is an `array of six char pointer` and here

```
 fgets(a[i], MAXLEN, fp); /* a[i] is a pointer & it doesn't have valid address, storing something into unreserved memory causes seg.fault */
```

it cause the **segmentation fault** because you are trying to store `MAXLEN` bytes into each `a[i]` but you didn't allocate memory for the same to store into it. Hence either first allocate memory for each `a[i]` like below & then store data into it or you can use two dimensional char array like `char a[num_of_line][max_char_line];`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
 a[i] = malloc(MAXLEN); /* you can allocate as per req. */
 fgets(a[i], MAXLEN, fp); /* read manual page of fgets(), it stores \n at end of buffer in some condition, be aware of that */
}
```

Also check the return value of `fopen()` and `fgets()`. And once usage of dynamic memory is done, free the dynamically allocated memory to avoid memory leakage.

Comment: This is phrased a bit misleadingly.  There *is* memory allocated (automatically) for each array element.  But those elements are pointers.  For them to be useful for the OP's purpose they must be assigned to point to space into which `fgets()` can write up to `MAXLEN` bytes.  That the pointers are separate from and independent of the pointed-to spaces seems to be part of the OP's confusion.  Note, too, that the pointed-to spaces do not necessarily need to be dynamically allocated.

Comment: Agree @JohnBollinger

Comment: Better now, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger for correcting.